# Music Notation - Little notes

Tags: notation

Can someone please tell me what the little notes (4 bars after C) are called?

[image]

Comment: Karelia Suite, right?

Answer (score 30):

These are called "*cues*" and they show you what other instruments are playing while you have rests.  They are normally placed right before an entrance, particularly after a long section of not playing, so that you can be sure of when to come in.

"*Tromb. e Tuba*" means that these notes are being played by the trombone and tuba.  (The markings in this music are in Italian.)

Answer (score 17):

They're cue notes.  Notice the "Tromb.e Tuba" below them, indicating that the trombones and tuba(s) are playing those.  It's there to reassure you that you've counted the rests properly.